# WebBrowser control auto refresh

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control, refresh

I want to make a program in Visual Studio 2008 in Visual Basic. It involves a web browser and I want to make it auto refresh and allow people to choose the time period in which they want to auto refresh. It won't take user input but I have checkboxes that are preset. I think this may be possible using a timer and the `WebBrowser1.Refresh()` method. If I am mistaken, please correct me and tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, it seems that you are trying to create a WinForms application in VB.NET. To accomplish your goal, you can:

1. **Create a NumericUpDown or Textbox control** to allow users to select a refresh time period (you can decide whether you want this to be in seconds, minutes, or something else).
2. **Create a Timer object**, and using the TextChanged event of the textbox or the **ValueChanged event** of the NumericUpDown control, set the entered value equal to the interval of the Timer.
3. **Create buttons that call the Timer's start and stop function**, to allow the user to start and stop auto-refreshing.
4. **Subscribe to the Timer's Tick event** and **call the WebBrowser's Refresh method** when the event is raised/fired.

Here's some sample code.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub numInterval_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles numInterval.ValueChanged
        Timer1.Interval = numInterval.Value
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        Timer1.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
        Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        WebBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, I have added event handlers to Timer1.Tick and numInterval.ValueChanged.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a setting in "Properties > Settings" Tab for the interval you want to set for this I am going to name it `unlimitRefresh` and make sure it is a string and set the scope to user. After that I would make the interval options a DropDown button with every interval you want set and then I would make a two timers and for the first one I would set the interval to 1 and have it find out what the settings tab says. Then for the code for that I would type:

```
Timer2.Interval = My.Settings.unlimitRefresh
```

And then for timer one set that to whatever you want it on. Then for the code I would type:

```
WebBrowser1.Refresh()
```

After you are done just go to your dropdown button and double click each button for code and after that you type in:

```
My.Settings.unlimitRefresh = TYPE-THE-INTERVAL-HERE
```

Example:

```
My.Settings.unlimitRefresh = 100
```

After that it should work fine.

Also, I do realize this post is really old but just in case somebody does view it.